# FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext() returns null

Tags: spring, jsf, facelets

I would like to get the spring context from within a class that gets loaded at server startup time:

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

In Tomcat, this returns what I want, but in Weblogic this returns null. looking further, it seems that

```
getApplicationMap().get(
            WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE); 
// "org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT"
```

doesn't yet have that property in the map at the time of my class being loaded.

My class is constructed/loaded via roughtly this stack trace:

```
MyRenderKitImpl()
Class.newInstance()
RenderKitConfigProcessor.process()
ConverterConfigProcessor.process()
ApplicationConfigProcessor.process();
FactoryConfigProcessor.process();
StandardContext.listenerStart()
```

Is there a trick to ensure the right sequence?

Comment: Also, on Tomcat I see that org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.registerWebApplicationScopes() gets called 1st thing. In Weblogic it doesn't.

Comment: Well, it seems that Weblogic likes to load ConfigureListener BEFORE ContextLoaderListener.